# I need to get multiple index's instead of one using linq

Tags: c#, .net, list, linq

This should be very simple but I searched and couldn't find a similar linq example.

I have a function below.

```
viewModel.SLGDeptSalesList = viewModel.SLGDeptSalesList.Where(
    (value, index) => index == 0).ToList();
```

It returns an index within the sales list.

I need to customize it to return multiple hard coded index's such as 1,3,4,6.

How can I use linq to do this in one line?

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: What's `SLGDeptSalesList`? And what do you want to extract from it?

Comment: I suppose I need an and somewhere.  So this is going to return index 0.  I need Index 1,2,3, and 5.

Comment: You mean you need values at indices 1, 2, 3, and 5?

Comment: Yes those values at indices.  Hey everyone thanks for all the answers.  They all work beautifully.

Comment: Do you want an Exception when the index isn't found, or should it return the elements it does fine?

Comment: That's actually a very good point Mercer.  If one uses this method on multiple times on the same list then eventually there will be a time when one of the index's will be out of range.  I actually only needed to use it once so it worked out for me, but I suppose putting in an else for out of range index's would be a very good idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a `Select` on your hardcoded list of indices, to transform them into corresponding elements in the `viewModel.SLGDeptSalesList` list:

```
viewModel.SLGDeptSalesList = new List<int> { 1, 3, 4, 6 }.Select(x => viewModel.SLGDeptSalesList[x]).ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use `Contains` on an array:

```
var indices = new [] {1, 3, 4, 6};
viewModel.SLGDeptSalesList = viewModel.SLGDeptSalesList.Where(
  (value, index) => indices.Contains(index)).ToList();
```

Using `Contains` on an array is a common technique when you have queries you want to execute on SQL (not in your case, but in general), e.g. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/alexj/2009/03/25/tip-8-how-to-write-where-in-style-queries-using-linq-to-entities/

Comment: Works beautifully.  Thanks!

Comment: Just note that `Contains` is O(n), which means when used in a `Where`, the whole query becomes O(n^2).

Comment: @Sweeper In general it's not O(n), e.g. `Hashset.Contains`. And even for an Array it would never be O(n^2), it would be O(n*m) and we already know that m is 'hardcoded' so nowhere close to infinite.

Comment: @IanMercer I admit that's true, but IMO it's still bad habit. _This time_ the array is hardcoded, what about next time? And I didn't mean to say that this is inherently bad. Sorry if I used the wrong words.

Comment: @Sweeper thx, both answers are good. Choice comes down to readability and desired behavior when an index is missing, also whether any other conditions need to be added on `value`, and whether this query ever needs to move across to execute in SQL not locally.

Answer (score 1):

If your indexes are hardcoded in a list then you can just use the .Exists() within your Where. but if they are just

```
   var indices = new List<int>(){1,3,4,6};
   viewModel.SLGDeptSalesList = viewModel.SLGDeptSalesList.Where((value, index) => indices.Exists(index)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

There is already the built-in LINQ method [`ElementAt`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.elementat), so we could also have an `ElementsAt` that accepts multiple indices.

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> ElementsAt<TSource>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source, params int[] indices)
{
    var indicesHashSet = new HashSet<int>(indices);
    return source.Where((x, i) => indicesHashSet.Contains(i));
}
```

This implementation returns the elements in the order they are found in the source, and ignores duplicate indices.

Usage example:

```
viewModel.SLGDeptSalesList =
    viewModel.SLGDeptSalesList.ElementsAt(1, 3, 4, 6).ToList();
```

---

**Update:** Here is an alternative implementation. This one returns the elements in the order of the indices, and in case of duplicate indices returns duplicate elements. In case of indices out of range no exception is thrown, but no elements are returned for those indices. So it is not guaranteed that the output sequence will have equal length with the requested indices.

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> ElementsAt<TSource>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source, params int[] indices)
{
    return indices.Join(source.Select((Item, Index) => (Item, Index)),
        i => i, p => p.Index, (_, p) => p.Item);
}
```

---

**Update:** And here is a scholastic variant of the previous implementation. This one guarantees that the requested indices and the output sequence will have equal length. An exception is thrown for indices outside the bounds of the source sequence.

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> ElementsAt<TSource>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source, params int[] indices)
{
    var indicesHashSet = new HashSet<int>(indices);
    var foundElements = source.Select((Item, Index) => (Item, Index))
        .Where(p => indicesHashSet.Contains(p.Index))
        .ToDictionary(p => p.Index, p => p.Item);
    var notFoundIndices = indices.Where(i => !foundElements.ContainsKey(i)).ToList();
    if (notFoundIndices.Count > 0)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(indices),
        $"Indices [{String.Join(", ", notFoundIndices)}] " +
        $"are outside the bounds of the {nameof(source)} sequence.");
    return indices.Select(i => foundElements[i]);
}
```

Comment: That's some intense stuff Theodor!  Your very knowledgeable! Thanks!

Comment: My pleasure JSkyS! :-)

Comment: why not simply use  ElementAt within a for loop?

Comment: @PontiacGTX a LINQ operator that operates on `IEnumerable<T>` sequences is supposed to enumerate the source sequence exactly once. That's because the source sequence might be deferred. It might be generated dynamically by reading a database etc.

Comment: yeah but I was thinking in terms of a collection using the indexer or ElementAt() and doing yield return would be basically better, because in the second example you have to convert a collection to a Dictionary but in case of Database you should extend the type from IQueryable<T>

Comment: @PontiacGTX if you have a specific idea about how to improve the `ElementsAt` operator, feel free to post it as an answer. If it's a good answer it'll be be upvoted, if not it'll be downvoted.